# Adding two string numbers in python and get answer in string by using their ASCII keys

Tags: python

We need to add two numbers in string format and return a string.

E.g.:

```
a='11',b='5'
answer='16'

n1,n2='11','6'
sum=str(((ord(n1))+(ord(n2)))-96)
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use int() to convert a string into an integer

```
n1,n2='11','6' 
s = str(int(n1) + int(n2)) 
print(s)
```

Note that this will raise a ValueError if n1 or n2 cannot be converted into an int.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but does this help?

```
a, b = '11', '5'

sum = int(a) + int(b)
print(chr(sum))
```

---

```
Output: ►
```

It will combine the a and b values and print out the character with the resulting int value?

Comment: but i need to add two numbers ascii and written their ascii

Answer (score -1):

To add two string numbers in Python and get the answer in a string using their ASCII keys, you can use the built-in 'ord()' function to convert each character to its ASCII value, add the ASCII values together, and then convert the sum back to a character using the 'chr()' function.

Comment: but ord() taking only one character Ex:for '11' it is getting error